# Subequations and boxed with \hline

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, boxes, rules, subequations

I've a trouble with this code:

```
\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\Quadre}[1]{\left[#1\right]}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
z^1=|z|^1\Tonde{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}^1&=|z|\Tonde{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}\\[1mm]\hline
z^2=|z|^2\Tonde{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}^2&=|z|^2\Tonde{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta}\notag\\&=|z|^2\big[\cos{\Tonde{2\theta}+i\sin{\Tonde{2\theta}}}\big]\\[1mm]\hline
z^3=|z|^3\Tonde{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}^3&=|z|^3\big[\cos{\Tonde{2\theta}+i\sin{\Tonde{2\theta}}}\big]\Tonde{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}\notag\\&=|z|^3\big\{\cos{\Tonde{2\theta}}\cos\theta-\sin{\Tonde{2\theta}}\sin\theta+\\&+\qquad\:\:i\Quadre{\sin\theta\cos{\Tonde{2\theta}}+\cos\theta\sin{\Tonde{2\theta}}}\big\}\notag\\&=|z|^3\big[\cos{\Tonde{3\theta}}+i\sin{\Tonde{3\theta}}\big]\notag
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

I'd like to have that the numbers (1.1.1.1a), (1.1.1.1b), (1.1.1.1c) of equations are centralized at half of the vertical space that equations cover. Moreover I'd like that equations are separated from themselves via a `\hline[1mm]`. In conclusion I'd like to write these equations in a box and at the end aligning all. How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of using begin{align} for all three equations. You can use as follows 

```
\begin{subequations} \begin{equation}...\end{equation} ... \begin{equation}...\end{equation} \end{subequations} ```

Comment: @fromthebeeland Ok but how?

Comment: It is not good. Overleaf gives me 5 errors, that are: Misplaced alignment tab character &, 4 times and Misplaced \noalign. Why?

Comment: A box for each equation, or a single box for the whole set?

Comment: A box for each one

Comment: How or where is `\Tonde`  defined?

Comment: \newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

Comment: Thanks. And how about `\Quadre`?

Comment: \newcommand{\Quadre}[1]{\left[#1\right]}

Comment: So `\Tonde` and `\Quadre` do the same thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127783/discussion-between-puck-and-mico).

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `split`.

I removed all occurrences of `\Tonde`, that I guess you define with `\left` and `\right`. Don't. I also removed several useless braces.

The first version uses rules, the second one avoids them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
z^1=|z|^1 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^1
  &= |z| (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\\
\midrule
\begin{split}
z^2=|z|^2 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^2
  &=|z|^2 (\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta) \\
  &=|z|^2 \bigl[\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)\bigr]
\end{split} \\
\midrule
\begin{split}
z^3=|z|^3 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^3
  &=|z|^3 [\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)](\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) \\
  &=|z|^3 \bigl\{\cos(2\theta)\cos\theta-\sin(2\theta)\sin\theta +{} \\
  &\qquad\qquad+i[\sin\theta\cos(2\theta)+\cos\theta\sin(2\theta)]\bigr\} \\
  &=|z|^3[\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)]
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
z^1=|z|^1 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^1
  &= |z| (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) \\[1ex]
\begin{split}
z^2=|z|^2 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^2
  &=|z|^2 (\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta) \\
  &=|z|^2 \bigl[\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)\bigr]
\end{split} \\[1ex]
\begin{split}
z^3=|z|^3 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^3
  &=|z|^3 [\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)](\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) \\
  &=|z|^3 \bigl\{\cos(2\theta)\cos\theta-\sin(2\theta)\sin\theta +{} \\
  &\qquad\qquad+i[\sin\theta\cos(2\theta)+\cos\theta\sin(2\theta)]\bigr\} \\
  &=|z|^3[\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)]
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the mathematician's hat on, this is a perverse way to illustrate De Moivre's formula.

Comment: Thank you, but \Tonde and \Quadre very simplify the code! Why Mustn't I use them?

Comment: I proofed De Moivre's Formula with induction-way on n. Furthermore Overleaf tells me that there are two errors at line of \end{align}: 2 times Undefined control sequence Why?

Comment: @Puck I don't think you simplify that much; and using `\left\right` indiscriminately is wrong. Did you add `\usepackage{booktabs}`?

Comment: No. I add it now

Comment: Now it works perfectly, Thank you so much. Best Regards